# How do you do natural logs (e.g. "ln()") with numpy in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, logarithm, natural-logarithm

Using numpy, how can I do the following:

```
ln(x)
```

Is it equivalent to:

```
np.log(x)
```

I apologise for such a seemingly trivial question, but my understanding of the difference between `log` and `ln` is that `ln` is logspace e?

Answer (score 264, accepted):

[`np.log`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.log.html) is `ln`, whereas [`np.log10`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.log10.html) is your standard base 10 log.

Comment: For those who were wondering what np is, like myself

"import numpy as np"

Answer (score 25):

Correct, `np.log(x)` is the Natural Log (base `e` log) of `x`.

For other bases, remember this law of logs: `log-b(x) = log-k(x) / log-k(b)` where `log-b` is the log in some arbitrary base `b`, and `log-k` is the log in base `k`, e.g.

here k = `e`

```
l = np.log(x) / np.log(100)
```

and `l` is the log-base-100 of x

Comment: what about loss of precision?

Answer (score 22):

I usually do like this:

```py
from numpy import log as ln
```

Perhaps this can make you more comfortable.

Comment: Even more consequent `from numpy import log as ln, log10 as log`; but probably not so advisable.

Answer (score 1):

Numpy seems to take a cue from MATLAB/Octave and uses `log` to be "log base e" or `ln`. Also like MATLAB/Octave, Numpy does not offer a logarithmic function for an arbitrary base.

If you find `log` confusing you can create your own object `ln` that refers to the numpy.log function:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from math import e
>>> ln = np.log  # assign the numpy log function to a new function called ln
>>> ln(e)
1.0
```

Answer (score -3):

```
from numpy.lib.scimath import logn
from math import e

#using: x - var
logn(e, x)
```

Answer (score -3):

You could simple just do the reverse by making the base of log to e.

```
import math

e = 2.718281

math.log(e, 10) = 2.302585093
ln(10) = 2.30258093
```

Comment: note `math.e` exists and `math.log` takes the base 2nd. so `math.log(10, math.e)` is correct, while the above would actually return ~0.43...